# Switch between two nvidia-settings metamodes from commandline

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

Ubuntu 10.04 with Nvidia restricted drivers running Nvidia 9600 GT with dual DVI monitors (22" and 23"). In the default metamode (1), both monitors are active. I've added a second metamode via `nvidia-settings` (version 1.0) in which only the 23" monitor is enabled. I can switch between metamodes using the `nvidia-settings` GUI. Is there a way to do this from the command line? I've read about *Disper* on this site but have not tried it as I hoped this functionality was available via `nvidia-settings`?  I can find nothing helpful in the man page though.

Edit: After switching between the two metamodes in `nvidia-settings` GUI, I noticed a line in the GUI reading "Switched to MetaMode AxB.", where A and B specified the new resolution. So switching metamodes is simply a resolution change? I've read elsewhere that what I want to do can be achieved with `xrandr`. Would this be correct, because it seems all I need to do is change the resolution? In metamode 1, the resolution is 3600x1080; in metamode 2 it's 1920x1080.

Answer (score 1):

You almost gave the answer yourself.
`xrandr -s N` switches to metamode N, so you can use `xrandr -s 0` and `xrandr -s 1` to turn the second monitor on and off. Works fine on my pc.

EDIT: Found one problem:
I have both panels at the bottom. After swiching the Metamode, they share the same height (only one is visible, switches randomly when mousing over). I have to set one to top and back to bottom for the other to be displayed above it.

EDIT: Found solution: Use `gconftool-2 --dump /apps/panel` to get the current settings, move the panel, get the changed settings and find what changed with `diff`.
Using that information I created two files, one for pannel at the top, one at the bottom. Now I can script change of the Metamode and moving the panel.